# Fast access large data on Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, bigdata

Very recently we started running a website server (using node and mongodb) on Amazon AWS EC2. The website is meant to run validation algorithms on 3d model data that can be up to 100MB in size.

As a feature, we are thinking of providing storage volume and a management system for these models. The user should receive a list of already uploaded models at login and be able to quickly re-run the algorithms if desired.

How is such a scenario best implemented for running on Amazon's EC2? What kind of data storage is best suited for the large file sizes and fast retrieval of the files? Is e.g. the storage in the mongo database possible/a good idea?

Comment: you may look into S3 Buckets

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Seems exactly what we need!

Comment: S3 sound feasible.  But  `quickly re-run the algorithms if desired` is a bit strange. Unless the algorithm change, otherwise, there is little need to rerun any validation that consume CPU processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/details/) Buckets

> Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) is object storage with a simple web service interface to store and retrieve any amount of data from anywhere on the web. It is designed to deliver 99.999999999% durability, and scale past trillions of objects worldwide
>
> Amazon S3 stores data as objects within resources called "buckets". You can store as many objects as you want within a bucket, and write, read, and delete objects in your bucket. Objects can be up to 5 terabytes in size.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you attach some general purpose SSD (gp2) volumes to your EC2 instance ([read more](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html#EBSVolumeTypes_gp2)). This way you get a reasonably priced storage along with an acceptable (depending on your need, but seems enough in your case) performance. If you need better performance you should cache your files in the memory. Either way, scalability should be considered.

If you need scalability, go for [S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html). But it will be slower and of course cheaper.

Comment: "Slower" is somewhat subjective.  The biggest limiting factor is likely to be network bandwidth on the instance itself, not on S3.  The turnaround time before data starts flowing will be longer (milliseconds for S3, microseconds for EBS) but the actual transfer rate of large objects or files should be comparable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach here is to use EBS volumes (GP2/SSD) and avoid using S3 if you want fast access, low latency file access. The reason S3 is not recommended is because it is object storage and is not attached to EC2 instances via a close proximity network connection. Block / EBS storage is better suited to intense applications with larger files that require faster processing times because it is network attached (to the EC2 instance) storage.